# Add a new instance variable to subclass of http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python-3.x, http, basehttprequesthandler

I want to be able to add an instance variable to my subclass of [http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler).

Here's my code:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import urllib


class Server(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self, request, client_addr, server):
        super().__init__(request, client_addr, server)
        self.pathobj = urllib.parse.urlparse(self.path)

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self.send_response(200)

    def do_GET(self):
        print(self.pathobj)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        print(self.pathobj)
        self.send_response(405)
        self.end_headers()   

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=Server, port=8080):
    server_address = ("", port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)

    print("Starting httpd on port {}...".format(port))

    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

I want to be able to access the `ParseResult` object returned by `urllib.parse.urlparse` in each class method without needing to rewrite `self.pathobj = urllib.parse.urlparse(self.path)` at the beginning of every class method.

The above code does not work -- when `do_GET` or `do_POST` are called it complains that `'Server' object has no attribute 'pathobj'`.

The above [docs for http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler) say:

> All of the relevant information is stored in instance variables of the handler. Subclasses should not need to override or extend the `__init__()` method.

But I don't see another way to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say

> The handler will parse the request and the headers, then call a method specific to the request type.

As it turns out, `http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler` ultimately inherits from `socketserver.BaseRequestHandler`, and `socketserver.BaseRequestHandler.__init__()` (defined [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/302df02789d041a09760f86295ea6b4dcd81aa1d/Lib/socketserver.py#L741)) calls `do_GET()`. So the issue is that the instance variable is actually being set after `do_GET()` has already been called.

So in order to make this work, you'll need to move the `self.pathobj` line above the `super()` line and then rewrite it to do the parsing that `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` does to construct `self.path`.